# can not build my project Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

> Could not resolve all files for configuration
> ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>
> > Failed to transform exifinterface-1.3.2.aar (androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.2) to match attributes
> > {artifactType=android-assets, org.gradle.category=library,
> > org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external,
> > org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release,
> > org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > > Could not find exifinterface-1.3.2.aar (androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.2).
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/exifinterface/exifinterface/1.3.2/exifinterface-1.3.2.aar

---

I can not build my project My project is modular and the following libraries are used inside

```
> object AndroidX {
>     private const val coreKtxVersion = "1.6.0"
>     const val coreKtx = "androidx.core:core-ktx:$coreKtxVersion"
> 
>     private const val appCompatVersion = "1.3.0"
>     const val appCompat = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion"
> 
>     private const val lifecycleVmKtxVersion = "2.4.0-alpha02"
>     const val lifecycleVmKtx = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVmKtxVersion" }
> 
> object AndroidXTest {
>     private const val version = "1.4.1"
>     const val runner = "androidx.test:runner:$version" }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Possible Solution

Most probably the problem lies with the SDK version.

.

1. So go to `build.gradle` file and check the target version there.
2. Go to SDK Manager -> and check whether the SDK is same as API level.